# Is it common to use the phrase “come with” without specifying with whom

Tags: phrases, word-usage, expression-choice

> We’re going to the pub. Want to come with?”

- I have heard this from an American colleague.
  Though this sounds odd to the majority of us, however, since I am not sure of the usage, I am asking how common is it to use the phrase *“come with” without specifying with whom.*

Comment: Its frequency depends on where you are. Where I am, (northern Minnesota, USA) it is quite common, I suppose because of the area's history of settlement by immigrants from Scandinavia. The directly analogous "Kommen Sie mit?" is perfectly good German; I do not know Norwegian or Swedish but they are pretty close relatives. So where are you?

Comment: I am in Japan, Asia

Comment: It is common in the Midwest. The "with" can be a substitute for "along." 
 On one hand and it saves time of saying "with you."

Comment: Yes, it's common in Midwestern English, at least. However, the _with_ is stressed, as if it were a phrasal verb, and it simply means 'accompany me/us', in a specific context, like planning an excursion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not quite a dupe: That question is asking about grammaticality, this is asking whether it's common.

Comment: @Barmar: The usage is obviously common enough to be *asked* about, and I really don't see the point of trying to quantify ***how** common* (answer: somewhere between *common as muck* and *rare as hens' teeth*). So if you think this question is sufficiently different that it should stand, all I can say is I don't agree.